# Sending email based on field name UTL_MAIL.send

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

How can I send an email based on what is entered into a apex Text field. eg If I enter **me@test.com** in :p6_supervisor, I would like the email to be sent to that person.

At present I have a preset UTL_MAIL.send which is working.

```
begin  
UTL_MAIL.send(sender    => 'test@test.com',
                recipients => 'test1@test.com',               
                subject    => 'Test,               
                message    => 'Please Note this is a test' );

end;
```

But of course its for another purpose, which is sending email to one recipient from a trigger.

Below is the Cursor example

```
create or replace function "email"

   ( name_in IN varchar2 )
   RETURN number
IS
   supervisoremail varchar2(30);

   CURSOR c1
   IS
     select 
supervisoremail
 from 
    EMPLOYEE,supervisors
 where TO_DATE(contract_start_period,'DD-MM-YYYY') < TO_DATE (SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') - 275
 and (supervisors.supervisorname = employee.supervisorname1
     or supervisors.supervisorname = employee.supervisorname2) 

 and employee_name ='test'
; 

BEGIN

   OPEN c1;
   FETCH c1 INTO supervisoremail;



   CLOSE c1;

RETURN supervisoremail;

END;
```

Comment: Any reason you're using UTL_MAIL instead of APEX_MAIL, which has some better features (including asynchronous emails and automatic rate limit)?

Comment: hi @JeffreyKemp there is no particular reason am using utl_mail , with that being said if the apex_mail is more effective am open to your knowledge because I have no knowledge on apex_mail

Comment: I've done a summary of the different options, for APEX I recommend apex_mail for simple emails because it provides transactional safety and rate limiting: https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2016/04/email-made-easier/

Answer (score 0):

It'll work, no problem. A simple way is to

- create a text item (`P6_SUPERVISOR`)
- create a button which submits the page; you need it so that `P6_SUPERVISOR`'s value is set into the session state
- create a process which calls `UTL_MAIL`; `P6_SUPERVISOR` item's contents is used as a source for the `RECIPIENTS` parameter. For example:

  ```
  UTL_MAIL.send (sender       => 'test@test.com',
                 recipients   => :P6_SUPERVISOR,
                 subject      => 'Test message - subject',
                 MESSAGE      => 'Test message - message body');
  ```

**[EDIT: how to send mails in a loop?]**

I'm not sure what you meant by creating a function; it returns just one e-mail address that, probably, belongs to name passed through the NAME_IN parameter (but you used the 'test' name in cursor query).

However, you specified that the function returns a NUMBER, while variable you're selecting the result into is a VARCHAR2. So, which one of these is true?

If you insist on a function, don't enclose its name into double quotes as you'll always have to reference it that way (double quotes, correct upper/lower/mixed case).

Furthermore, what is contract_start_period column's datatype? If it is DATE, don't TO_DATE it. The same goes for SYSDATE - it is a function that returns DATE datatype anyway, so it is *wrong* to convert it to date once again.

Here's an example which uses a cursor FOR loop (as it is easier to maintain) and sends mail to all supervisoremail addresses returned by that SELECT statement.

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select supervisoremail
                from employee e join supervisors s on s.supervisorname = e.supervisorname1
                                                   or s.supervisorname = e.supervisorname2
                where contract_start_period < sysdate - 275
                  and e.employee_name = 'test'
               )
  loop
    utl_mail.send(sender     => 'test@test.com',
                  recipients => cur_r.supervisoremail,
                  subject    => 'Test message - subject',
                  message    => 'Test message - message body');
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: nice ...... but added to that can I send to a supervisor whose email is already in a table. eg supervisor.email (table.columnname)

Comment: Why not? Set P6_SUPERVISOR item's type to be "Select List". Its List of Values query should select values from a table that contains e-mail addresses.

Comment: I understand what u are saying fully. but my next point is, lets say I forget about the textfield (:p6_supervisor) and I just want the email to be sent to preset emails in the supervisor table (supervisor.email (table.columnname) ). can I add that in the recipients also?

Comment: To all emails in the table? No problem either - that would be a simple cursor FOR loop that selects recipients and sends mail to each of them.

Comment: thanks for you help will try it ..but not to all just select when a where clause is activated but I understand you points.

Comment: am creating the cursor but am not getting the desired results to show

Comment: It is difficult to debug code you can't see. Please, post your code (along with sample data) by editing the question you posted so that we could see what you did.

Comment: info sent littlefoot